# einsammeln vs aufsammeln vs auflesen

Tags: meaning, difference, meaning-in-context

Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen:

**einsammeln**

> - Er wurde böse, sammelte seine Spielsachen ein und ging nach Hause. *(groups.google.com)*
> - Früchte (in einen Korb) einsammeln. *(Duden)*
> - Die Mutter sammelt die Spielzeuge ihres Sohnes auf der Wiese im Garten ein. *(easy-deutsch.de)*

**aufsammeln**

> - die Scherben [vom Boden] aufsammeln. *(Duden)*
> - Das Kind sammelt die Äpfel vom Boden auf und legt sie in einen Korb. *(easy-deutsch.de)*
> - Er sammelte die Briefe auf, die auf den Boden gefallen waren.*(reddit.com)*

**auflesen**

> - Fallobst, Scherben auflesen. *(Duden)*
> - die heruntergefallenen Glasperlen wieder auflesen. *(Duden)*

Comment: *Einsammeln* legt die Betonung auf das Hin**ein**tun in irgendetwas, während *aufsammeln* die Betonung auf das Hochnehmen vom Boden legt. *Auflesen* legt die Betonung auf das Ordnen durch Hochnehmen.

Comment: Wer Blaubeeren aufliest ordnet die im Normalfall nicht (nach Größe, chronologisch, Farbton, ...?).

Comment: Ich lerne gerade Deutsch und habe Schwierigkeiten mit einer Gruppe von Wörtern, die einander ähnlich sind. Die Frage ist nicht wirklich neu: Welche Verbindung sollten sie haben? Zum Beispiel hat Spielzeug eine Verbindung: eine Reihe von Dingen, die zum Spielen verwendet werden. Wenn diese konzeptionelle Grenze nicht funktioniert, was ist sie dann? Ich habe kein Problem damit, dass der Kommentar gelöscht wird. Mir gefällt die Struktur Ihrer Erklärung, ich möchte nur, dass Sie das Konzept der Verknüpfung etwas näher erläutern, weil ich es noch nicht verstehe.

Answer (score 3):

### lesen

Dieses Verb hat natürlich die Bedeutung »Schriftzeichen wahrnehmen und deren Sinn verstehen«. Diese Bedeutung ist aber später entstanden als die ältere, noch immer existierende Bedeutung »etwas auswählen und in die Hand nehmen um Gutes von Schlechtem zu trennen (z.B. Linsen, Erbsen usw.), etwas ernten (z.B. Wein)«

Die ursprüngliche Bedeutung des althochdeutschen Verbs *»lesan«* ist: aufheben, sammeln.

Auch das lateinische Verb *»legere«* und das griechische Verb *»λέγειν« (légein)* haben beide dieselben Bedeutungen (aufheben, sammeln, Schrift verstehen, Schrift mündlich wiedergeben (vorlesen))

---

### auflesen

Bei diesem Wort schränkt die Vorsilbe *»auf-«* die Bedeutung ein und modifiziert sie ein wenig. Das Bedeutungsfeld, das mit Schrifterkennung zu tun hat, existieret hier gar nicht mehr. Es geht nur um das Aussuchen und um das An-sich-nehmen. Gleichzeitig signalisiert *»auf-«* eine Bewegung von unten nach oben. Man wählt also etwas aus mehreren Dingen aus die am Boden liegen, und hebt davon jene auf, von denen man glaubt, dass sie es wert sind aufgehoben zu werden.

---

### sammmeln

Dieses Verb bedeutet: Gleichartige Dinge, die vorher auf verschiedene Orte verteilt waren, an einen gemeinsamen Ort bringen. In manchen Fällen ist auch gemeint, dass die Dinge danach für längere Zeit an diesem gemeinsamen Ort bleiben, diese Bedeutung ist aber nicht zwingend inkludiert. (*»Nachdem der Feueralarm losgegangen war, sammelten sich alle Mitarbeiter beim vorgeschriebenen Sammelpunkt vor dem Gebäude.«*)

---

### einsammeln

Die Vorsilbe *»ein-«* weist hier auf eine Bewegung hin, die von außen nach innen gerichtet ist. Die gleichartigen Dinge befanden sich vorher an verschiedenenOrten außerhalb einer bestimmten Grenze. Diese Grenze kann auch nur gedacht sein, und muss nicht exakt definiert sein. Nach dem Einsammeln befinden sich diese gleichartigen Dinge an einem gemeinsamen Ort innerhalb dieser Grenze.

---

### aufsammeln

Wie *»sammeln«*, aber mit der von unten nach oben gerichteten Bewegung, die schon beim Verb *»auflesen«* beschrieben wurde.

---

### Zusammenfassung

Die Stammverben:

- lesen = Qualität bewerten und dann auswählen
- sammeln = gleichartige Dinge an einen bestimmten Ort bringen

Die Vorsilben:

- ein- = von außen nach innen
- auf- = von unten nach oben

Hinweis:
Die Vorsilben können bei anderen Verben andere Bedeutungen haben (*einrichten, einschalten, aufstreichen, aufmachen*)

Answer (score 0):

*Eingesammelt* wird all jenes, zu welchem bereits eine gedankliche Verknüpfung besteht. Die Früchte eines Baumes ebenso wie Spielzeuge in fremdem Besitz können sprachlich nicht als *eingesammelt* wiedergegeben worden sein.

Bei *Aufsammeln* fehlt eben diese gedankliche Verknüpfung und stellt sie mit dem Ereignis eines Aufsammelns hierdurch erstmalig her.

*Auflesen* betont lediglich, dass ein Aufheben oder auch die Notwendigkeit eines erneuten Auffindens mit Mühsal verbunden empfunden wird. Eine räumlich höhere Ausgangsposition ist hierbei ebenfalls erforderlich. Kinder können von ihren Eltern aufgelesen werden, ältere Geschwister jedoch dies nicht von ihren jüngeren.